# Might be a silly question, but how do you set the label of a c# button ? (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, button

How do you set the label of a button ?

Here's my code :

```
private void InitializeMyButton()
{
    // Create and initialize a Button.
    Button button1 = new Button();
 
    // Set the button to return a value of OK when clicked.
    button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
 
    // Add the button to the form.
    Controls.Add(button1);
}
```

Hope someone could find a solution.

Comment: Why don't you use `button1.Text`?

Comment: `button1.Text = "OK Button";`

Comment: button1.Text = "Funny Name";

Comment: Youve clearly found [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) because your code is lifted straight from it - did you have a look for something likely to set the `Text` of the button?

Comment: Terminology matters. A Label is a control. So is a Button. Both have a .Text property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes that descend from `Control` have a `Text` **property** you can set for this, and a `Button` is one of those.. Some controls like Button and Label have a Text that isn't set by the user, only the developer. Others (TextBox) are user editable, and you'd read from the Text property to find out what the user has typed into it

Some controls don't really have a sensible use for a Text property (DataGridView, for example) but they descend from Control, so they have one (that isn't used)

In C# a **property** is like a variable: you set a value for it by putting it on the left hand side of an `=`:

```
label.Text = "Hello";
```

You can read from them too:

```
MessageBox.Show("You typed " + textbox.Text);
```

Methods and properties are different; methods "do something"; `.Show` above is a method; it shows a MessageBox, and you pass a string into it as an argument, but it's different to a property.

You don't set a property by invoking (running) it - your attempt in the comments `button.Text("My button label")` would work if button had a Text *method*, but `Text` on a button is a *property*, not a method..

When you're looking at C# for the most part you can tell whether something is a property or a method by seeing if there is an open parenthesis `(` following it. Methods also have verb names, whereas properties are nouns:

```
textbox.Clear(); 
textbox.Text = "hello";
textbox.AppendText("world");
```

Comment: Yup, but when I tried I used "button1.Text("text");"
Thanks for the help !

Comment: That's quite a JavaScript way of looking at the world.. In C# properties are like variables: they appear on the left hand side of an `=` if you want to set them. I'll clarify

Answer (score 1):

[`Button.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.text?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_ButtonBase_Text):

```
private void InitializeMyButton()
{
    // Create and initialize a Button.
    Button button1 = new Button();
 
    // Set the button to return a value of OK when clicked.
    button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;

    button1.Text = "OK"; 

    // Add the button to the form.
    Controls.Add(button1);
}
```

Comment: Simple but it wasn't not in my head, apparently.
Thanks a lot !